# Once a Node has been loaded in via FXML, how can all the item that have an fx:id be retrieved?

Tags: javafx

I'm looking to automatically detect all items that have been given fx:ids. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`namespace` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#CONTROLLER_KEYWORD) to get a `Map<String, Object>` containing the objects by `fx:id`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
loader.load();
Map<String, Object> fxIdObjects = loader.getNamespace();
```

Note that there may be additional keys in there:

- [`controller`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#CONTROLLER_KEYWORD)
- [`location`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#LOCATION_KEY)
- [`resources`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#RESOURCES_KEY)

Other than that the `id` property is set to the value of the `fx:id`, but you cannot be sure that the cause for the assignment was a `fx:id`, an `id` attribute or some java code.